# Prevent web page copying method

Tags: javascript, html

I was completely facinated when I discovered BRW's ([example](http://www.brw.com.au/p/sections/professions/computing_under_cloud_wI6seC6KDvn6TXJQlV5pWP)) method to prevent web page copying. I had a quick look through the source view and couldn't see how they did it. Aside from inserting (c) symbols through out the text, they also scramble the text yet it is completely readable through a browser. Amazing!

Any ideas how they did it?

Comment: It doesn't really work.  View it in a browser like firefox where you can see the dom and it's easy to pull the text out.

Comment: I have JavaScript disabled and all I see is gibberish. Can somebody tell me what this is supposed to do, besides piss people off and make Google hate your pages?

Comment: When I turned off javascript, the text was still presented with the (c)s in it and also the text was still completely scrambled. While it may appear to be an easy case of 'replace all' in your favourite text editor, the insertion of random words render it unreadable... essentially requiring a human re-write.

Comment: There is nothing clever or fascinating about sites wrecking their content, insulting their users and killing their search-engine rankings in the name of protecting their content. All they need now is to embed their text in a big jpeg and add a huge watermark.

Comment: @meagar Yes, I agree that it is insulting and frustrating, but from a purely web-programming perspective I was fascinated by it. From this perspective I thought it was clever, however in general terms you have raised good reasons why overly aggressive copyright management is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view the source, you will notice that its a boatload of `<i>` and `<span>` elements littered in the source (some of which are hidden by indenting them -10000 to the left). However, a simple scraper with a tiny bit of logic could easily undo that travesty.

Sure, it will prevent casual copy and paste, but is downright dumb, plus makes you pretty much ungoogleable.

Comment: The question is though, how did they do that?

Comment: @Paul: They pick a randomly generated CSS class name for their (c) afr.com text, which is indented -100000. You don't see it on the screen, but due to it being inline with the text the browser still copies it. The style is directly above the text block.

Comment: +1 there really is no point, if someone wants your content they are going to get it.  You have it displayed publicly.

Comment: Heck, a simple jQuery two-liner is all it would take to enable copying and pasting with no difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

They overlay/insert invisible text spans (through CSS: `text-indent: -100000px`) that browsers usually still copy and paste, resulting in too much copied text. You need to parse the CSS to determine what is readable (try lynx -- bad text)